# cucumber-jvm scala spring example

Tags: spring, scala, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to convert the **cucumber-jvm spring-txn** example to **scala** version.
As a first step I have converted the Java code to scala. In the **UserStepdefs.scala** the UserRepository is not getting injected, i.e is null in the Given function.

My question is why is the dependency not getting injected and how to make it so?

I have forked the cucumber-jvm project here
https://github.com/SaadKhawaja/cucumber-jvm

with the scala version here https://github.com/SaadKhawaja/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/examples/scala-spring-txn.

If someone would please like to give it a shot.

Thanks

Saad.

Comment: Can you post what code the compiler says is breaking and the error it gives you?

Comment: I added the compiler error message in the original post above. My Stepdefs class is not compiling. I think there is some issue with implicit conversion of the List[Message].

Comment: What's wrong with the uncommented version here: https://github.com/SaadKhawaja/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/scala-spring-txn/src/test/scala/cucumber/examples/spring/txn/UserStepdefs.scala ?

Comment: That is the Java way of doing it, cucumber-jvm for scala provides scala specific api which is commented out because its not compiling.

Comment: I updated the code I simplified the feature so that there is no parameters. My question is that in the Given function of UserStepdefs the userRepository is null and is not getting injected?